# Java arithmetic calculation

Tags: java, math, operators

How is this code evaluated?

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;
        System.out.println(i); 
    }
}
```

The answer is 75.

Please explain this code.

Comment: How do you think? What makes you think so? What happens when you run the code, do you get results which you ware expecting?

Comment: Thanks for (partly) ansering @Pshemo’s question. When doing so, it’s always best to edit the original question and add the further information there so we have everything in one place (you have an edit link under the question). This time I did it for you.

Answer (score 4):

The second `+`/`-` are unary operators, so this equals:

```
10 + (+11) - (-12) + (+13) - (-14) + (+15)
```

->

```
10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15
```

->

```
75
```